# Changing the address of a wordpress.com blog

Tags: wordpress.com

I have a blog hosted at wordpress.com and is accessible at `blog.mydomain.com`. I want to know if it's possible to change the address to `mydomain.com/blog` instead of `blog.mydomain.com`. And if yes, how can I do it?

Comment: Have you seen [this page](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/changing-from-blogmydomaincom-to-mydomaincom)?

Comment: Thanks. But that really doesn't apply in my case. My question is about moving a blog that is hosted in wordpress.com. So copying installation files or anything like that is not an option.